# Sharepoint Search Results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

I have a sharepoint list whose search results show up as Dispform.aspx when searched. It is not at all user friendly and the reason for it is because users have left the default Title field blank and replaced it with another field.

Could someone shed some light on where to edit this property of sharepoint search so that I can bind my custom field instead of default Title field.

Currently all sharepoint results appear as Dispform.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the Search Service Application and find the Metadata Properties. The bindings of the properties are all set there so you can add your custom field into the "Title" property.

Answer (score 0):

1. Central Admin -> Application Management -> Service Applications -> Search Service Application -> Metadata Properties (On the left side under Queries and Results)
2. Find the “Title” field in the list of properties and open it. Under “Mappings to crawled properties” -> Add Mapping for “Custom Column you want to display”  and save it.
3. Run a Full Crawl.

Now Search Results will display with the column name instead of Dispform.aspx.